# How to get the current user_id from the mysql using php?

Tags: php

I need to know the current `user_id` where this `user_id` is an auto increment column.

How to find the current user_id using php code?

Suppose, the last `user_id` is 23.

The next created user will have an user_id of 24. How to know this after executing the related `INSERT` query?

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`... and do **NOT** alter connection!!! And absolutely correct way is to select record using WHERE filter with filter data entered for that record while inserting.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a "predictive" answer - what will the *next* `user_id` be? One cannot necessarily guarantee what the next `user_id` will be in any multi-user system, as some other connection can insert a new record between when you make your prediction, and when you actually create the record. Are you looking to get the next `user_id` before it is assigned, or the `user_id` that is assigned to a new record once you insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last added user id, where id is auto-increment:

```
$n = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM tablename");
```

Thus, the return value of `mysql_query` gives it back to you. In your example, `$n` will be 24.

Comment: This is race-prone. If many rows are being inserted in parallel, selecting `MAX(id)` may give you a result reflecting a different row from the one you inserted.